# Удаление файлов с сервера. Unlink

Tags: php

Есть простая галерея картинок, с двумя кнопками - "загрузить" и "удалить", и инпут-чекбокс для выбора картинки, которую нужно удалить. Не могу разобраться, почему некорректно работает удаление-фото удаляется только из DOM, а из папки- нет. Панель разработчика выдает ошибку "unlink(upload/картинка.jpg): No such file or directory in C:......\OpenServer\domains\localhost\include\deleteFile.php"

```html
//файл deleteFile.php
<?php
//Конструкция для массового удаления файлов
if (isset($_POST['checked'])) {
    

    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/upload/';
    if (chmod($dir, 0740)) {
        echo "Права доступа для {$dir} изменены"; 
    } else {
        echo "Не удалось установить права для {$dir}";  
    }
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $check) {
        if (in_array(basename($check), $files)) {
            unlink($check);
        }
        echo 'Файл ' . (basename($check)) . ' успешно удалён<br/>';
    }
} else {
    echo "Ни одного файла не выбрано";
}
//js-обработчик формы

var response = document.getElementById("response");
const form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    xhr.open("post", "/include/deleteFile.php", true);
    xhr.send(formData);
    console.log(formData);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        response.textContent = this.responseText;
    }  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').forEach(func);
    function func(item) {
        item.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
    }
});
//форма с картинкой для удаления

<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/functions.php';
$images = glob('upload/*');
?>
<form id="form">
<?php foreach ($images as $image) : ?>
  
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img src="<?= $image ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="фото" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"><?= cutString(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_FILENAME)); ?></h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          Размер файла: <?= getSize($image) ?>
        </p>
        <input class="check-input" type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="<?= $image; ?>">
        <label class="check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
          Удалить
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          <?= "Изменялся:" . date(" Y-m-d H:i:s", filectime($image)); ?>
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: а у тебя типа есть на сервере папка C:......\OpenServer\domains\localhost\include\upload?

Comment: Да, но в корневой папке C:......\OpenServer\domains\localhost\upload, в include лежит обработчик формы

Comment: вот и я думаю что в корневой. а зачем ты пытаешься удалять из localhost\include\upload?

Comment: ой, а почему так? Я же пишу директорию -$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/upload/', потом ее сканирую $files = scandir($dir);

Comment: При чем здесь scandir вообще, если ты удаляешь $_POST['checked']? без всяких DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: Типа надо $_POST['checked'] тоже к DOCUMENT_ROOT прикрутить?